# Importing VB.net project A into VB.net Project B

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Could someone point me in the direction of importing a project into a project. Any information on how to use it would be great as well.

For example I have Project A that I could use to work within Project B. I have no idea what the correct form is for calling this in.

Any links would be more than helpful as well.
I am working in VB 2010

First Edit:

I do have an add reference option, but no add project option. Im assuming i shall go with reference and see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the solution in the Solution explorer and Add --> Existing Project should work

Or file from the main menu Add --> Existing project

Comment: Some configurations of Visual Studio do not show the solution node by default.  @harper89 may need to go too Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions and select the "Always show solution" check box.